# Div at the bottom of div

Tags: css

I have div containers that are placed below each other on a web page. (Its a "one pager")
I want to place a div at the bottom inside each of these divs.

Here is the css for the div that i want to place it inside.

```
#useit {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1550px;
    background-color: #333333;
    float: left;
}
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Why float left with a 100% width? Isn't this supposed to be a 'screenfull'?

Comment: Its an aerea that goes full bleed horizontally. I dont know any other way, this just worked for me :) Appreciate any tips or improvements!

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing at least the style for the containing element, what I can provide is this:

```
.container {
  position:relative;
}
.inner {
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  /* other properties */
}
```

Comment: The css i posted was the containing element. It is inside that div i want to place another div. Or is there anything else you mean?

Comment: If i set the container to relative it scrambles the whole page. Do i have to do it to all the containers that are below each other?

Comment: @JohnJohn you should use inner-class within the element you want to put inside a containing element. like <div id="container"><div class="inner">content</div></div>

Comment: When i changed all containers to relative the stacked correctly but the color background did not cover the whole aerea it was supposed to cover. I had to change a div inside with text from margin-top to padding-top. Anyone got a explanation for why this is?